# My C# code for a Unity Project does not work as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written code in C# for Unity with the intent of playing a list of 360-degree videos in a sequence. The next video should start playing once the previous video has finished playing. However, it works as expected only for the first 2 videos after which it starts giving intermittent issues. I can find that the index increments but the 3rd video is not visible - the scene still displays the second video. The second video continues to remain on the screen even for the subsequent indexes i.e. 3,4,5....

I have tried debugging the code to the best of my knowledge.

```
public List<VideoClip> videoClipList; //list of video clips
private List<VideoPlayer> videoPlayerList;
private int videoIndex = 0; 
//SerializeField
private RenderTexture _renderTexture = null;

VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlayVideo());
}

IEnumerator PlayVideo(bool firstRun = true)
{
    if (videoClipList == null || videoClipList.Count <= 0)
    {
       yield break;
    }

    //Init videoPlayerList first time this function is called
    if (firstRun)
    {
        videoPlayerList = new List<VideoPlayer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < videoClipList.Count; i++)
        {

            GameObject vidHolder = new GameObject("VP" + i);
            vidHolder.transform.SetParent(transform);

            videoPlayer = vidHolder.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
            videoPlayerList.Add(videoPlayer);

            videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;

            videoPlayer.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.RenderTexture;

            videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;

            videoPlayer.clip = videoClipList[i];

            videoPlayer.targetTexture = _renderTexture;
        }
    }

    if (videoIndex >= videoPlayerList.Count)
        yield break;

    videoPlayerList[videoIndex].Prepare();

    while (!videoPlayerList[videoIndex].isPrepared)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    videoPlayerList[videoIndex].Play();

    //Wait while the current video is playing
    bool reachedHalfWay = false;
    int nextIndex = (videoIndex + 1);

    while (videoPlayerList[videoIndex].isPlaying)
    {
        //(Check if we have reached half way)
        if (!reachedHalfWay && videoPlayerList[videoIndex].time >= (videoPlayerList[videoIndex].clip.length / 2))
        {
            reachedHalfWay = true; //Set to true so that we don't evaluate this again

            //Make sure that the NEXT VideoPlayer index is valid. Othereise Exit since this is the end
            if (nextIndex >= videoPlayerList.Count)
            {
              yield break;
            }

            //Prepare the NEXT video
            videoPlayerList[nextIndex].Prepare();
        }
        yield return null;
    }

    //Wait until NEXT video is prepared
    while (!videoPlayerList[nextIndex].isPrepared)
    {
      yield return null;
    }

    //Increment Video index
    videoIndex++;

    //Play next prepared video. Pass false to it so that some codes are not executed at-all
    StartCoroutine(PlayVideo(false));

}
```

}

Comment: Are you intentionally using recursion mixed with asynchronicity (i.e. PlayVideo() called in PlayVideo())? As a pattern it might add confusion. On a side note, consider factoring out the video list initing into its own function, then calling it right in the Start() function (or check against the list being null, as it removes the need for firstRun).

Comment: The script runs perfectly fine when I use it for 2D videos. Even if I add ten 2D videos to play in a sequence, they play one after the other without any breaks or overlaps. Thus, there does not seem to be an issue with logic. There seems to be something that creates an issue when 360 videos are used.

Comment: Gotcha. What happens if you switch, say video 1, 2 and 3 (the files themselves) with videos 7, 8, 9, but keep the code the same -- will it again stall on the second/third video? (If so, it would rule out issues with the specific video content of 1, 2 or 3).

Comment: It seems that the problem was with a specific video. I will try to figure it out later since this video has the same resolution and frame rate as the other videos. However, the code works fine after this particular video is removed from the playlist. Thanks for your support @PhilippLenssen.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help!